# How to index and store multiple languages in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, search-engine, elasticsearch, multilingual

I am trying to figure out gow to index the following in ES.

I have a lot of documents which are crawler from website with **various language**. Each 
document has a category such as Airport, restaurant, river, beach 
etc ., and it's language such as **Arabic, English**.. like

doc { language:"eng" , content :"something here" , category:"beach" }

doc { language:"vn" , content :"Xin chao" , category:"beach" }

I want to index and search documents with each languages;

I choose English options, and search with query " here " => RESUTLS

**Should I :**

1. Setup each Elastic Core ( per machine per language) for per
   language. JUST COPY ES to run  :)

   Eg : create elasticsearch_ENGLISH, elastichsearch_VIETNAMESE
2. created each language with each index of ElasticSearch 
   Eg: create indexs

/english/*type/*

/vietnames/*type/*
.
 When I search some query, I just search only index of language

**OR do it some other way I am not aware of  :) ?**

Answer (score 10):

Not sure I fully understood your concern.

If you need to search on the full cluster (I mean search in every language), you can't create one setup per language.

That said, you have many options:

- Create one index per language and have a mapping for each index/type.
- Use the _analyzer field to indicate the language for your document. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-analyzer-field.html
- Use a multifield with a different analyzer for each language. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html

It's not a full answer but some clues to help you...

Comment: Thanks dadoonet,:)  there one index per language is the best for this situation

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks. I have just updated the links in your answer as it seems the pages have moved.

Comment: there's a good post about this here http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/